# How to Only Check All Other Checkboxes From another Checkbox in a Group Chechbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to only enable checking (Not Unchecking) all other chechboxes in a group checkbox from one of them like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="all" />All Genders <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="women" />Women <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="men" />Men<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="bi" />Bi<br />
```

what I need to do is checking all `women, men and bi` checkboxes when user clicks all but uncheck it only by code when user clicks on one of the other options?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="all" />All Genders <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="women" />Women <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="men" />Men<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="bi" />Bi<br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("click", "input", function (evt) {
  if($(this).hasClass('selall')) {
    $('input').prop('checked', true);
  }
  else
  {
    $('.selall').prop('checked', false);
  }
  if ($('.gender:checked').length == $('.gender').length) {
    $('input').prop('checked', true);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="all" class="selall" />All Genders <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="women" class="gender" />Women <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="men" class="gender" />Men<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="bi" class="gender" />Bi<br />
```

Comment: Thanks Germano, this is very close to what I need but how to unchecl `All Gender` when one of `Women, Men, or Bi`?

Comment: Not sure if i understand but Edited.

Comment: Thanks ,just one minor update, how can I check `All Gender` when all other chechboxes are checked?

Comment: Code edited. Added control to check all if all checked :)

Answer (score 1):

add an event listener for the first `checkBox` and when it changes, if it's `checked` then `check` all the `checkboxes` :

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (this.checked)
    inputs.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.checked = true;
    });
});

inputs.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (!this.checked)
      document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').checked = false;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="all" />All Genders <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="women" />Women <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="men" />Men<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="product" value="bi" />Bi<br />
```

Comment: Hi Taki, thanks for the code but this is not exactly what I need. 1- cheching the women, men bi must uncheck all gender and 2- how to kinda disable all Gender directly. I mean the uncheck process only be able by one of the other 3 checkboxes